# Eject CD-ROM Drive after application Installation

Tags: linux, installation

I have an application in Linux that installs from a CD-ROM Device.

When the CD-ROM is inserted into the Drive, the autorun feature runs the installation script in an xterm window. Now when the installation is over, I do an 'exit 1' , and the xterm window prompts the user to 'press any key to close the window'. My problem is that I would like the script to eject the CD-ROM Drive after the Installation is over.

However since the installation script is still running from the CD-ROM Drive, the script cannot unmount the CD-ROM Drive and eject the Drive.

Could any please give me some idea of how the script could possibly eject the CD-Drive after Installation?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a local installation script that refers to the installation files on the CD.  That does mean your user will have to copy the file locally in order to start running the installation program.

Another option could be that  your installation program could create the supplementary install file when the user starts the install process from CD.

Answer (score 0):

Before the installer starts, copy the installer and an "eject CD" shell script to the `/tmp` directory on the Linux machine. Then, execute the installer from `/tmp` and create a shell script that executes, or find a way to execute, the following commands:

```
sudo umount /dev/cdrom
eject /dev/cdrom
```

Also, on some machines it's `sudo umount /dev/sr0`, but `/dev/cdrom` *should* work.